# Is God wasteful, according to geocentrist models of the universe?

Tags: young-earth-creation, technology, economics, outer-space

The economy of God is unbeatable and without peer, as evidenced for example by the fact that, even as semiconductor design and engineering is approaching atom-scale electronics, human and animal brains are still [orders of magnitude more energy-efficient](https://press.princeton.edu/ideas/is-the-human-brain-a-biological-computer) and capable than the world's most sophisticated microchips. God has also succeeded at creating enormous fusion reactors the universe throughout while scientists still struggle to get hints of the feasibility of such technology under carefully controlled laboratory conditions.

This question is for young earth creationists who believe that all other stars, galaxies and objects in the cosmos were created attendant to the Creation of this Earth, and that there is no life on other worlds (other than perhaps spirits or eternal beings pertaining to, or known by the people on this Earth), or that this Earth is otherwise unique in terms of theological significance or its place in the universe in some pre-eminent way. I refer to these beliefs as "geocentrist" models because they make everything in the universe effectively revolve around this Earth and its purposes. I do not say they deny that the Earth revolves around the Sun, but they still make everything in the universe effectively accessories to this Earth and its Creation.

What reasons do they give for why God with such mind-boggling extravagance would create so many other galaxies, stars, solar systems and even planets--given for example the gargantuan amounts of energy that each star outputs--if not a one of them sustains life of its own, or has any other purpose except towards this Earth and its populace? That would actually make life on Earth less energy-efficient than the most primitive creations of mankind, by a large margin. Obviously there are other ways to measure this, but again, why waste the vast, vast, vast (with many zeros added on for good measure) majority of starlight and creative effort on something so far away that our telescopes cannot resolve 99.999999% it to more than a mere point of light?

God is doubtless generous, with trillions of photons devoted to striking our eyes each second, and efficiency isn't everything, but is He wasteful? This is a natural question asked by those who ponder why God would create so many quintillions of stars, but only one with life in its system?
Why would He break the pattern of sustainable life on other worlds, forfeiting the opportunity to have and redeem quadrillions of quintillions more of His children, when the resources are clearly there and already organized to sustain life? Or if they are not organized in such a fashion to sustain life, surely He has the intelligence to do it--is there some other limitation or reason why, other than simply that He can?

To be clear, this is not *my* question or criticism, but rather is a natural question or criticism levied by some secular scientists and engineers regarding common interpretations of Genesis. They might have a point, not against God's ways, but that should help us to correct our own misunderstandings. What can we say that will address the criticism and instruct our own ways?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150567/discussion-on-question-by-pygosceles-why-is-god-apparently-wasteful-according-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: If you're going to claim other people are accusing God of being wasteful, then you need to provide some quotes.

Comment: @curiousdannii The spirit of the criticism is already captured in the post; it is perfectly eligible to be addressed as it stands. I get the feeling most people are downvoting this and asking for it to be closed because they think this is my position, but it is not. I have encountered the spirit of nihilism and borderline nihilism too often (complaining that God supposedly made the universe mostly empty or seemingly imperfectly are among these) and I find there are things we can do in the way we think about and present Christianity that can help to remedy that.

Comment: Nope, we need quotes that demonstrate the position being asked about. We need to be able to see for ourselves what they're saying, because what if you're misunderstanding or misrepresenting what they said? And of course we thought it was your own position, when you didn't give us any indication it wasn't!

Comment: @curiousdannii I have given many indications that this is not my position. Folks should have a little patience, enough to forbear.
If this is what I understand of the concern, I appreciate being able to answer what I think their concern is and let them see its relevance on those merits, rather than having people trying to psychoanalyze or label me for potentially having deficient understanding of a criticism. I believe I understand it well enough, let the question stand, as it is a valid question that I believe deserves a sensible answer rather than a dismissal.

Comment: In all the comments we wrote to each other you never wrote anything that hinted you weren't expressing your own thoughts on the topic. Statements like "*But eternal extravagance and wastefulness contradict the lessons in mortality about efficiency and thrift, hence the question.*" really only look like something you yourself think. Regardless, the question needs at least one quote from a notable person who does think it.

Comment: @curiousdanii You must not have looked much. I answered this question too.
It is a nonsensical standard you just made up. Very few questions here have a "quotation from a notable person who thinks X". Most are simply "What is a good answer to X?" without a whole essay of backstory etc.
It's easy to counter many about efficiency since macroevolution (even if it worked) would be the most inefficient mechanism for bringing about life and they know this, so it's not a common or widely publicized question. But that doesn't answer it.
You're also moving the goalposts as you go, so please stop.

Comment: @curiousdannii Are you asking to cite some well-known person who thinks this so that you can judge people based on their perceptions or beliefs? I see no other reason to ask for this. It adds neither information nor clarity to the question.

Comment: This subject matter of this site is the published teachings of groups or significant individuals. Personal eccentric or unique positions and theologies are off-topic. When we thought this was your personal position it was extremely borderline off-topic. By showing some other people think this (as you claim, so it should be easy!) you would demonstrate that the question is on-topic. It's just not fair to ask a question about some position we can only know about second hand, through your recollection and reinterpretation. We always want to go back to the sources!

Comment: I'm pushing, because the way you're presenting this question is non-sensical. As I've said before, "waste" just isn't a concept that makes sense with the type of creation the Bible describes God doing. If you present a quote then maybe the question might make sense.

Comment: @curiousdannii ""waste" just isn't a concept that makes sense with the type of creation the Bible describes God doing" - That is a blind spot of one's own religious interpretation then, in that it diminishes the capacity to compassionately address the inquiries of those who do not hold to the same interpretations or concepts of belief.
Waste avoidance is a concept that makes perfect sense to millions of people who spend their days diligently keeping the commandment to labor six days, and perform all their work (whether they realize that this is a Divine commandment or not).

Comment: @curiousdannii Since you haven't submitted an answer to the question, may I ask if you are coming from a perspective of ex nihilo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150576/discussion-between-pygosceles-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't see a uniform desire to go back to sources; as I said, on many questions, no such context or further sourcing is provided nor is it asked for. I do see a desire to push back on questions that cause discomfort regardless of the source. Where I come from, it is always fair to ask any sincere, relevant and impactful question, and one does not have to be on an in-crowd or ask a question on a pre-approved list. Is that not the case here?

Comment: Notice, this question appears to have been closed on grounds of the moderators' bias, not for any legitimate reason. It is not lacking clarity in the slightest; it is answerable as it stands and already has five answers.

Comment: Have look at this old meta discussion: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1407/6071 For other questions it may be clear who the question is talking about; for example many of the Catholic Church's doctrines on Mary are close to common knowledge. Others aren't, and so quotes from Catholic sources are helpful. This question is not relevant or impactful without you demonstrating that it is, and you do that by showing who the people making these claims/questions are. Otherwise how can we know if there even is anyone thinking it's wasteful?

Comment: Also think of it this way: if someone needs to ask more about the argument before they write an answer, who can they ask? Not you, if you're not an actual proponent. So we need the source of the argument so that we can read more about it, or possibly even send off an email to ask directly.

Comment: @curiousdannii I am far from the only one on here asking a question that is not original to myself, and that does not at the same time quote some venerable professor posing that very question. If you have such a question you are free to ask it and I can rely either on my experience and knowledge of the concern or inquire among those who might still hold it or a substantially similar one. Until such an unresolved concern appears, there is no problem to speak of, and nothing preventing anyone from answering the question as it stands.

Answer (score 5):

First, **Why would God, with such extravagance, create so many other galaxies, stars, solar systems and even planets?**

Let me quote answers from highly accredited scientists (who believe God created the universe and all life in it, for a purpose. They will be Old Earth Creationists.) This quote is from Michael Poole, BSc (Physics), King's College London. He also wrote the book *User's Guide to Science and Belief*, (Oxford: Lion Hudson, 2007):

> "Genesis says that God made Adam out of dust. Science seems to have a
> similar view as it says we are made of dust from imploding stars. How
> can we be made of star dust? It is reckoned that after the first three
> minutes of the universe, matter consisted of hydrogen and helium.
> Gravity then drew these gases together. The closer they came, the
> higher the temperature rose. Eventually they burst into incandescence
> and stars were born.
>
> The temperatures were so huge and the energies were so high that the
> nuclei crashing against each other fused and built up into heavier
> elements, such as carbon, nitrogen and oxygen - the basic building
> materials of life. Some stars imploded at the end of their life,
> scattering these elements into space. The process then repeated on
> second-generation stars. Gradually, the atoms of life were built up.
> Our bodies are made up entirely of these atoms. If we want to sound
> romantic, our bodies are 'star dust', 'the ashes of long-dead stars'
> if we don't - or, to sound really grim, our bodies are reprocessed
> nuclear waste'.  But there is not a nucleus of a carbon atom in our
> bodies that wasn't made in a star. That, to me, really is
> awe-inspiring." *God, The Big Bang and Bunsen burning Issues*. Ed.
> Nigel Bovey., p48, Authentic, 2008

Here is astrophysicist, Rev. Dr. Rodney Holder, MA (Maths) Cambridge; DPhil Astrophysics, & BA (Theology) Oxford:

> “Scientific discoveries, such as the fine-tuning of the universe, feed
> my faith and deepen my appreciation of God. For example, the universe
> in its initial phase – the first fraction of a second from the Big
> Bang – had to be set up in a very special way in order for stars,
> galaxies and ultimately life to form. Cosmologist Fred Hoyle did some
> major work on the nuclear reactions that go on inside stars to form
> all the chemical elements out of the simplest building block, which is
> hydrogen. He discovered that there needs to be a very fine balance of
> the forces in nature in order to make carbon, and then to make oxygen
> without destroying the carbon. Although he didn’t believe in God,
> Hoyle said that his work led him to the conclusion that there was a
> super-intellect behind physics, chemistry and biology, and that there
> are no blind forces worth speaking about in nature...”
>
> “Right back at the beginning, the universe needed to be very close to
> that knife-edge in order for stars, galaxies and planets to form. The
> mass-energy needed to be what it was to within 1 part in 10\60 (that’s
> ten with sixty noughts after it). That kind of accuracy would be the
> same as firing a gun from one end of the universe to the other (some
> 10 billion light years away) and hitting a coin you were aiming at.
> The question is, Was that a lucky shot or are you a brilliant
> marksman. Likewise, is the fine balance of the universe a lucky
> happenstance or is there a brilliant designer behind it? I believe
> that there’s a brilliant designer behind it.” (*Ibid.* pp.169-70)

Prof. Bob White, BA (Natural Sciences & PhD (Geophysics) Cambridge, said:

> "The universe is extremely finely balanced... There had to be the
> right force of gravity, the right forces of attraction and repulsion
> in the nucleus, the right electrical forces and so on, otherwise
> matter as we know it, and ultimately life itself could not exist. One
> way of looking at that is to say that we're here just by chance. But
> as a Christian I see it as evidence that a gracious and loving God
> created a place just right for us to inhabit." (*Ibid.* p.146)

Second, **Human brains are orders of magnitude more capable than the world's most sophisticated microchips.** This was in an article in the London *Times* newspaper, 22 January 2016, p.1, as reported in the book below. The article was headed, ***"Think Big - your brain can store 4.7 billion books"***:

> "Terry Sejnowski, professor of computational neurobiology at the Salk
> Institute in California, has found that the part of the brain that
> deals with memory has a capacity ten times bigger than previously
> thought and could store data roughly equivalent to the entire contents
> of the worldwide web." *What is Man? Adam, Alien or Ape?* Edgar
> Andrews BSc, PhD, DSc, FInstP, FIMMM, CEng, CPhys., p8, Elm Hill, 2018

Andrews then quotes Sejnowski on the brain's low energy but high computational power. Here is what Andrews makes of that:

> "If we could use this enormous memory storage capacity, of course, it
> could be interpreted as the outcome of 'survival-value' Darwinism, but
> we can't. We regularly forget the names of acquaintances and where we
> put the car keys - and I doubt whether many of us could memorize even
> one book, let alone 4.7 billion. In other words, we have failed to
> evolve any means of accessing this huge potential memory capacity,
> which therefore can do nothing to help us reproduce. So why do we
> possess these potential powers of memory? No naturalistic theory of
> evolution can answer this question. I might add that there are many
> other human characteristics that have no plausible reproductive value
> such as the ability to handle and enjoy musical, aesthetic,
> philosophical and mathematical concepts. Humble bacteria reproduce far
> more efficiently than human beings." (*Ibid.* p9)

He goes on in his book to explain how Jesus Christ is "the second Adam", and "what humanity will, one day become - when those who trust in his redeeming work will escape condemnation and live with him in 'new heavens and a new Earth in which righteousness dwells.' (*Ibid.* pp274-291) And that is the Big Clue as to why human brain capacity is so extravagantly capable yet economic. Adam was created perfect, with a mission from God as to living on Earth, but disobeyed and died. Deterioration set in. Jesus Christ was the only perfect man whose death ensures the future removal of the heaven and the Earth as we know it, to be replaced by God with a new heaven and a new Earth, in which righteousness will dwell - 2 Peter 3:7-13 & Revelation 21:1-5. Nothing will be wasted in the scheme of God, but used to restore the universe and humanity to a perfection and capability we cannot imagine (given we can't see further than the end of our own noses, compared with God!)

***Nothing is wasteful in the geocentric view of God's abundantly generous creation.*** It is sinful humanity that is wasteful, destroying God's lavish provisions. But the day is coming when "God will bring to ruin those ruining the earth" (Rev.11:18). Let those who appreciate the brain and The Book God has freely given them take note, and use both, to God's glory.

Comment: Well-resourced answer, Anne. Please edit the date vice year of publication of article on human brain in  London Times. It can't be 1016.

Comment: A very different aspect from mine but equally valid and edifying. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4):

Almighty God scattered galaxies by the billion, supernovae without number,  trillions of suns - like dust he scattered them - like a farmer striding through the field, hurling seed to right and left - gloriously, he did so . . . . . . . just because he could !

And what is man to question why he did so ? Man is just a miniscule part of the immensity.

The ways of the Creator are not so much an engineer with a toolbox, but rather an artist with vast array of colours and a million ways of expressing them on canvas.

Yes, the supporting structure is meticulous, intricate and intensely mathematical. But the end result is breathtakingly glorious and beautiful, full of splendour and magnificence.

Nor is the most and best of his work seen in planets and stars and galactic displays.

The crown of his creation is humanity.

And more than this, for out of that humanity comes another humanity and out of that comes many sons to the glory of God, for ever and ever.

And far greater than the engineering of creation is the salvation of the Lord God, through Jesus Christ his Son, in an everlasting testament unto a New Creation, through redemption, justification, propitiation and remission.

> For it became him, for whom are all things, and by whom are all things, in bringing many sons unto glory, to make the captain of their salvation perfect through sufferings.  [Hebrews 2:10 KJV]

Comment: How do you reconcile these two statements:
"And what is man to question why he did so ? Man is just a miniscule part of the immensity."
and
"Nor is the most and best of his work seen in planets and stars and galactic displays.
The crown of his creation is humanity."
?

Comment: @pygosceles I shall leave you to construct your conundrums and I shall glory in the Lord my God.

Comment: It is much, much easier to make a movie than it is to build something real and living. We both do ultimately know that.

Answer (score 3):

If one person looks up at the night sky (say, out in Utah somewhere where there is little or no light pollution) and, seeing an uncountable number of lights, is driven to fear-filled awe of the eternal power of the Godhead ([Romans 1:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201%3A20&version=KJV)) and deep humility, gratitude, and worship of his Creator...

And if another person looks up at that same sky and thinks, "What benefit is there to any of this?  What a waste of resources!  If I had created this I would have populated the whole universe with beings to directly benefit from all of this energy in the same way that I currently benefit from the sun and, since I will one day become God and create my own universe (in what I currently consider to be a non-wasteful manner) that must be how this creation was done.  Since I'm going to become God someday, God must have done it my way."...

Which person has responded properly to God's stated purpose for the creation of the heavens:

Psalm 19:1

> The heavens declare the glory of God; and the firmament sheweth his handywork.

And which person worships God and which person worships self? ([Romans 1:21-23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201%3A21-23&version=KJV))

Let it be enough for everyone or let them answer:

Job 38:2-4

> Who is this that darkeneth counsel by words without knowledge? Gird up now thy loins like a man; for I will demand of thee, and answer thou me. Where wast thou when I laid the foundations of the earth? declare, if thou hast understanding.

Comment: Much appreciated. Very pertinent. Up-voted +1.

Comment: The question is not at all "what benefit is there to any of this", the question is "What am I missing about the same Creator who made octopi so efficient and so clever that they have miniature brains in their arms? What more can He teach me?" as opposed to being entirely content with a mere "Oh, it's just a light show" or "it's just lifeless art".
Knowing God entails that we expect continuity of His pattern and consistency.
A being who does not continue to create, or who did it just for giggles, what would such a being have to teach anyone? My God is greater than that.

Comment: @pygosceles, perhaps the intent *is* to teach you (us) to appreciate the art of Creation. Or to teach you (us) humility. (Also, to serve as "signs and seasons", to help with time keeping and navigation.) Being *open* to deeper meaning is fine, but *demanding* that such be present starts to feel like Mike is very much on point. Remember also, God says "My thoughts are not your thoughts"; we may not be able to comprehend exactly why He does some things. (At least, not in this life.)

Comment: @pygosceles All of God's artwork on this Earth is pretty functional as well. It would be a satisfactory answer to me to be open to more, rather than shutting the subject down and saying, "nope, that's all there is to it". It's not like I am not moved by the beauty, but all that is beautiful also exists for more good reasons and that is part of what makes it beautiful.

Comment: @pygosceles, as hinted at in KJS's Answer, have you considered that *we just don't know*? Ancient people didn't know that octopi have miniature brains in their arms, among many other things that we know now. Perhaps the mysteries of the cosmos are reserved for future generations to discover.

Comment: @pygosceles The entire third paragraph in your original posting is exactly that question, sir.  It is right and good to learn all we are capable of and to praise and fear the One who makes us capable so long as we do not lose sight that we inquire into unsearchable depths of wisdom when we ask, "What am I missing about the Creator?".  If one knows a thousand things about the infinite God, how much more is there to learn?  Infinity minus 1000 equals....

Comment: @MikeBorden "We just don't know" is not a very satisfying answer admittedly insofar as it is indistinguishable from a *shrug* or "no reason", or if it asserts "nobody knows". "There is much we have to learn" is a great answer and an honest one. 
And honestly it is probably very healthy in one's theology and epistemology to answer "I don't know" to a question that reaches beyond the boundaries of our understanding--so long as the answer doesn't add, "but don't ask, don't answer, don't go there, don't try to learn", then I'm good with that.

Comment: @Matthew I'll admit I need to distinguish here between an answer that says "here are the reasons that I give", even if I don't like all of those reasons, and something that doesn't answer the question at all. Part of what I am pushing on here is, Should what we do know or observe cause us to be incurious, or anxious to learn more?
If looking at God's handiwork causes us to be incurious, that is a value system in itself, but I'll admit that's not what I think when I see and wonder at His creations.
Mind that claims such as "we don't know" transgress wholesome boundaries of epistemic humility.

Comment: @Matthew If you think "We don't know" would make a good answer of its own as more than a hint, feel free to submit it as such.

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily ad hominem, -1

Answer (score 2):

If anyone assumes that science has been able to understand how the universe works, he is to be pitied on. Even elementary forces like gravity are beyond comprehension. For instance, the earth is much bigger compared to the moon and therefore exerts more gravitational pull .But then, we depend on moon's pull to have the tides on earth!  There is a delicate balance in the solar system that coordinates among other things,  the force of gravity without which life would have been impossible on earth. Who knows if the entire universe is part and parcel of that balance! Let us leave the outer world alone. The human brain itself defies explanation. Its capacity to store information and to retrieve it in such manner as can be interpreted by the five senses, is somthing a person would take thousands of years to fully utilise ! But, all of us  including the 100 plus years old, ' die young'. A simple joke summarises the paradox: a devotee asks " Lord, my hundred years' time is equal to your one second and my 10 million dollar is equal to your one dollar. So, why don't you give me one dollar ?" God replies: " Yes, I will; but just wait a second "

Comment: Your answer has triggered in my old brain a recollection of a book where various scientists addressed such matters. The book is not very old, but my memory of the scientific points raised is not up to speed, so I will go look it out now and post an answer shortly, to complement yours.

Comment: The OP makes reference to multiple things that only one who tries to follow in the footsteps of the Creator can appreciate--directing away from this doesn't accomplish the objective stated in the OP, which is to understand more, not wring our hands and say it can't be done. The Scriptures invite us to ask, and receive.

Comment: You are right, pygosceles . Unless and until we define how much is too much, or how many are too many, or how long is too long , etc etc, we may not find an answer. For that reason, your question will stand in the q , I mean ' queue' of unanswerable questions ( Now, please don't ask why the word ' queue' has five letters when the first one would pronounce the same )

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan I have faith that this question has a good and correct answer. Why else would God invite us to ask? Track record is that every time we ask in faith, He edifies us with His answers, which expand our souls, hearts and minds far beyond our preconceptions.

Comment: It is acceptable in CSE to post answer to one' s own question , and even to green-mark the answer. If you already have an answer in mind, make it a part of the question itself and ask for views . Best of luck .

Answer (score -1):

While geocentrism can be true in a very important sense--This world at least appears to us to be unique as the one to which the Only Begotten Son of the Father came to atone for our sins and make reconciliation for us with God on conditions of repentance--this does not imply that all of God's other creations are lifeless.
(I do not claim to know how other worlds stand with respect to the status of this one, given that the Savior came here. I am a geocentrist in the sense that I call this Earth home and it is my primary mortal frame of reference, and I know the Savior condescended to our very mortal sphere on which we now stand; I am a young Earth creationist in that I believe this Earth was organized by God fewer than 6000 literal Earth-years ago).

In Moses's account of the Creation we read:

> And God said, Let there be lights in the [expanse] of the heaven to
> divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for
> seasons, and for days, and years:
> And let them be for lights in the [expanse] of the heaven to give
> light upon the earth: and it was so.
> And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day,
> and the lesser light to rule the night: **he made the stars also.**
> And God set them in the [expanse] of the heaven to give light upon
> the earth,
> And to rule over the day and over the night, and to divide the
> light from the darkness: and God saw that it was good.
> And the evening and the morning were the fourth day.
> (Genesis 1:14-19)

It is interesting to me anyway that "he made the stars also" is given in a manner indistinguishable from a parenthetical statement. This statement does not seem to convey an explicit temporal designation of *when* He made the stars. Also curious is the fact that if one assumes a strict chronological telling, then there is light before the Sun is made, proving anachronism, metaphor, or an alternative source of light than our own current Sun, Moon and stars if we make such an assumption. I do not purport to know the source or exact nature of that first light nor what the exact sequence of Creation was, and this question is not about that. Suffice it to say I do not believe the Creation account proves that the stars were all formed during the self-same creative period as this Earth and its Sun and Moon. It does not say that they were. Whether they were or weren't, it is **not implied** by the Creation account that no other world is inhabited or that other star systems are not useful or economical in their own right.

Relative to this world, God says the lights in the heavens are to give light on the Earth, for times and seasons, and to distinguish day from night. Obviously the Sun and Moon do this job superbly, and the stars make a beautiful accompaniment in the night sky (One does not need stars in the sky to know that it is night-time; it will be dark. The stars do help us to know the season, as does the length of the day and the rising and setting points of the Sun and its angle in the sky during the day.)

The realization that each star corresponds to an object like our Sun, though most are very appreciably different in size, color, proximity and even shape and other variability, brings unimaginable vastness to the scope of the plan of our God. We must all ask, as the psalmist:

> "What is man, that thou art mindful of Him?"
>
> Psalm 8:4

As far as seeming wasteful, I will admit I do not understand the designs of God in letting the vast majority of energy radiated from our own Sun escape into space. Only a tiny fraction of it reaches this Earth, and only a portion of that is converted into chemical energy used to sustain the living beings. This would seem to dwarf our notions of geocentrism, hence the question about why God even bothers with man or what is the significance of man to Him. Modern scientists have understood that the amount of energy capable of being harnessed emitted from any star is so great that it would take a great mind to make appropriate use of it, and so have proposed [Dyson spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) and other similar structures in an effort to capture as much radiation energy as possible.

Perhaps this is a cautionary manifestation of the adage, "What one selfishly keeps, one loses": If we tried selfishly to absorb all of the energy the Lord made available to us, as though it were for our own individual and exclusive means, we would shine more dimly for others. This is perhaps the ultimate example of the Savior's words,

> Do men light a candle and put it under a bushel? Nay, but on a candlestick, and it giveth light to all that are in the house. A city that is set on a hill cannot be hid.

For all I know, God uses that energy in some way for some productive or creative process somewhere (or perhaps everywhere) in the galaxies and universe. After all, each star is a fusion reactor that converts lighter atoms into heavier atoms, many of which are essential building blocks we know He uses to create mortal life. The light we see is a byproduct of this conversion reaction. It would not surprise me if the light emitted from stars into the far reaches of space is instrumental in bringing about some additional conversion in the economy of God's infinite plan that we know nothing of.
Among other valuable properties, the stars provide a very long-lived mechanism for navigation. Given that the purpose of our mortal lives is to be worthy and return to live with God forever, I cannot imagine that navigation is a fruitless or wasteful purpose for stars. He does not apparently mention this in the Creation account, but as every ancient mariner knew, the stars are useful for navigation even on this Earth.

The planets in our solar system consist of copious amounts of matter, yet their purposes remain largely unknown to many (although I believe we will see greater signs from them in the future, and this is well worth the energy and effort).

This is the utilitarian and engineer in me, trying to analyze what happens to that precious energy we sometimes find ourselves drooling over as our power bills hit new highs even as our homes are sometimes left with too little heat during seasons of our lives. And yes, the stars are absolutely, stunningly beautiful and awe-inspiring, which is one great reason why I wonder that anyone can be glued perpetually to artificial screens, day or night. I seem to recall Isaiah had something to say about where relying only on the sparks of our own light will lead.

As for life on other worlds: It would of course be a non sequitur to say that because someone else's light shines on you, that they have no light for themselves.
There is no Scriptural prohibition anywhere that says that God did not create life on other worlds. I believe He has populated planets more numerous than we can imagine. There is no good reason I can see nor that my spirit feels why not, according to His purpose of sharing perfect love with supreme and unfathomable generosity. It is real faith there, that says to me, that He has additional other sheep. This may assuage some of our concerns that light and energy are simply leaking into the cosmic drain of nowhere. God loves all of His children, and I know of no corner of the universe anywhere, be it infinitely vast, where at least a particle of His light does not shine.

And perhaps that is an embodiment of another glorious parable: That God does leave the ninety and nine sheep in their sheep-pen, and goes to every length, even all eternity with His love to search out those whom He could rescue, who have strayed, or who sit in darkness, illuminating their souls with the inescapable outreaching of His love.
This is the testimony that is in me. And with that in mind, no matter how many spare gigawatts we wish we had to spend on our own purposes, I am assured that His purposes are doubtless accomplished in that light that spreads itself abroad the universe throughout, no matter how many vessels of oil He has to burn or fusion reactors He has to spend to the uttermost doing so, day and night throughout the countless eons.
The upper lights are burning. Shouldn't we keep the lower lights burning as well, to help some grieved and marooned mariner home?

God does not change.
He didn't just create, He still creates.
We observe this happening as stars near and far continue to move, to be born, and to die.

Some have mentioned art, beauty and awe. Beauty is powerful, art is expression, and awe is a crucial ingredient to eternal life. But what is art for? What are music's sublime expressions? To tell the story of redemption, and heal the wounded heart. To bring unto the power of the Son. Whose light is it that we feel, that turns our hearts, and changes our minds, making us able to understand? It is His light, every time.

The economy of creation, to my mind and spirit at least, is explained by God's loving desire to continue forever creating and redeeming, to seek that which was lost, and never to cease to be the Light that shines in the darkness, even though the darkness does not comprehend Him.
Creating, sustaining, and being a light to those who sit in darkness is never wasteful. God is not wasteful at all.

Comment: Downvoter(s), kindly add a comment to explain your criticism(s) and how this answer can be improved, rather than only disliking it because of theological differences of opinion.

Comment: Pygosceles, I have always wondered why Genesis does not say " God created darkness" . Mind that the average temperature of the universe is just above Absolute Zero. It means that all the fire and light that the universe has, is nothing compared to the darkness it holds. Scientists now agree that the so- called vaccum is not totally devoid of any substance. In fact, the more we know about Creation, the more we realise our ignorance. Perceptions keep changing. They have to !

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Of course the so-called vacuum contains substance, and "holding darkness" would be a meaningless notion besides, since darkness is merely the absence of light! I love having learned that true scientific discovery and religious revelation are always perfectly consonant.

Comment: ...And perceptions change in such a way that those thing which looked simple, start looking complicated - be it about the slanting of earth on its axis , or how the sprout of a seed pushes upward through hard soil , or why the raven keeps turning its head . The list goes on and on !

Comment: Perhaps, you can get a clue from Jn 6:12-13 which speaks of the leftover after the miracle of bread :"When they had all had enough to eat, he said to his disciples, “Gather the pieces that are left over. Let nothing be wasted.” 13 So they gathered them and filled twelve baskets with the pieces of the five barley loaves left over by those who had eaten. " Jesus could very well have counted the people present and made loaves just enough to feed each one. He didn't . See the beauty of God's abundant care  for human beings !